# What happens with delayed result instructions on branch in ARM assembly?

Tags: optimization, assembly, arm

I am optimizing an algorithm in ARM assembly and need to figure out in which order to place the instructions to minimize pipeline stalls. The cycle counter at http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/index.php?lng=us is very useful in this, but lacks knowledge about what happens on function calls/branches. What I want to do is basically (this is just an example):

```
mul       r4, r0, r1
mov       r0, #0
mov       r1, #12
mov       r4, r4, ASR #14
str       r4, [r5]
bl        foo
```

The pipeline stall between the `mul` and `mov` instructions is quite horrible, and there is nothing stopping me from doing the function call between them. But what exactly happens with the pipeline when I do the branch? I know that `foo` will do `push {r4-r12, lr}` as it's first instruction. I can see two possible outcomes:

1. The branch instruction takes a few cycles which enables the `mul` instruction to deliver its result before `push` is performed, thereby reducing the pipeline stall.
2. The pipeline stall is increased since `push` needs `r4` a few cycles before it is executed (this was the case before ARMv7 IIRC, the cycle counter in the link does not seem to think this is needed).

In short:
What happens with instructions with delayed results (`mul` being the prime example) when you do a function call (which is assumed to push the register on the stack) or even a normal branch?

Comment: You will only get a pipeline stall when you try to use a register which is not ready. This is the point of pipelining - the instructions continue to execute even though the previous results are not ready yet.

Comment: Yes I know, that was the whole point of the question. `r4` is not ready when doing the `mov r4, r4, ASR #14`. Will I reduce the pipeline stall by doing the function call before the `mov` instruction even though the function pushes the register in question onto the stack?

Comment: Why do you assume there will be a pipeline stall at the mov? The multiply instruction should only require 1 or 2 extra clocks depending on the version of the ARM core. If for some reason it does take more than 2 clocks for r4 to be ready, the BL will give it more time.

Comment: I think you need to time it. Dont make any assumptions between the prior gen and next gen, pipelines, everything can be totally different. Michael Abrash, Zen of Assembly Language, used copies are readily available. One of the themes is no matter how well you think you understand what is going on, you still need to time it, experiment, and verify.  Also, try crazy things and time those too and figure out why the shoulda been slow answer was so much faster.  You need to time it with all caches off, i cache on and i/d on, mmu on and off, etc. (to find there will not be a single concrete answer)

Comment: @BitBank: Instructions like `mul` and `ldr` only take one or two cycles if you don't try to use the results directly afterwards. Even though the instruction looks like it has finished, trying to use the result until several clock cycles later will result in a pipeline stall (which is why you want to interleave instructions that are independent). Read the timings in the reference manual or check the calculator and you will see what I'm talking about. Performance can be increased quite a lot if you interleave instructions in an optimal way.

Comment: @dwelch: Good suggestion and more or less what I have been doing, but it is always nice to have some theory behind the experimentation.

Comment: @Leo I know all about instruction interleaving and unlike your guesswork, I actually test the code to see if my theory is correct. As I said in my comment and you obviously missed - "1 or 2 EXTRA clocks".

Comment: @BitBank: Sorry, missed the EXTRA word. Of course I test which will give the best results, but I still want to know the theory behind it if possible. In this case, I could see no measureable difference, but if I encounter something similar at some other time it might. http://pulsar.webshaker.net/ccc/sample-85cdb1dd seems to show that there will be a pipeline stall between `mul` and `mov` which is consistent with the numbers in the TRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you don't need to execute

```
mov       r4, r4, ASR #14
str       r4, [r5]
```

before the call.
Doing the call before the mov

```
bl        foo
mov       r4, r4, ASR #14
str       r4, [r5]
```

is a good idea.

The mul will have more time to finish during the call.
the STM will be a problem that's clear. Of course you can push R4 before it's computed.

If foo is an asm function, you can save R4 later in the foo function (may be you can try to not use r4 and then not save it).

if foo function is a C function (or if you can change the push instruction). use r12 instead of r4 as the destination register of the MUL.

R12 will be needed later by the STM instruction. Then it is possible that the mul have enough time to finish before the destination register (R12) is needed by STM !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the answer is, but I'm pretty sure that if the answer is publicly known then it'll be in the [Cortex-A8 Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/index.html).